# validate flash in html

Tags: flash, xhtml

Recently i made a site with football betting predictions. I then contacted some bookmakers and got the affiliate links . My problem is that my page doesn't validate with the affiliate code in it. Is there any way to "hide" the code so it can pass the validate? Here are 2 samples of the affiliate codes

```
                    <object 
classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
codebase="https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" 
id="2b768569182449adaac3eddd9bbafde9" 
width="600" 
height="30">
<param name="movie" value="http://imstore.bet365affiliates.com/?AffiliateCode=365_077851&CID=194&DID=141&TID=2&PID=149&LNG=20&ClickTag=http%3a%2f%2fimstore.bet365affiliates.com%2fTracker.aspx%3fAffiliateId%3d45066%26AffiliateCode%3d365_077851%26CID%3d194%26DID%3d141%26TID%3d2%26PID%3d149%26LNG%3d20&Popup=true">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="allowNetworking" value="external">
<embed 
src="http://imstore.bet365affiliates.com/?AffiliateCode=365_077851&CID=194&DID=141&TID=2&PID=149&LNG=20&ClickTag=http%3a%2f%2fimstore.bet365affiliates.com%2fTracker.aspx%3fAffiliateId%3d45066%26AffiliateCode%3d365_077851%26CID%3d194%26DID%3d141%26TID%3d2%26PID%3d149%26LNG%3d20&Popup=true" 
quality="high" 
allowScriptAccess="always" 
allowNetworking="external"  
swLiveConnect="false" 
width="600" 
height="30" 
name="2b768569182449adaac3eddd9bbafde9" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
wmode="transparent">
</embed>
</object>
```

And the second

```
<a href="http://partner.sbaffiliates.com/processing/clickthrgh.asp?btag=a_42587b_3173"  >
<iframe allowtransparency='true' src='http://ff.connextra.com/selector/client?client=%53portingbet%47reece&placement=sbaffiliates_150x150&tclk=http://partner.sbaffiliates.com/processing/clickthrgh.asp?btag=a_42587b_3173&url=' width='150' height='150' scrolling='no' 
frameborder='0' style='border-width:0'></iframe></a>
```

About the errors well ... there are 2 many. so  i will just give you the link of the site (it's still not ready specially the layout so dont't comment anything else :p)

http://www.advancedbet.com/

PS: I have tried different doctypes with no luck :(

Comment: I fixed the first affiliate using http://validifier.com/ .The second one, i removed the <a> i changed the & to &amp; and added an if IE for allowtransparency

Answer (score 2):

You could just correct the given code to have it validated...
The main issue I see here is open tags (`<param>` should be `<param />`).

And maybe empty tags (`<iframe></iframe>` instead of `<iframe />` and `<embed></embed>` instead of `<embed />`). Not 100% sure on this one though.

Answer (score 1):

You might try surrounding the offending code with a CDATA comment block, though I have a feeling that only works in XML or Javascript.

Alternatively, you could URL-encode the offending URL, or maybe try using `&amp;` in place of `&`.

Edit: Kodiak is correct; `<embed>` and `<iframe>` require closing tags, not just the "quick close" of `/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Often HTML doesn't validate with some snippets of code. This doesn't only counts for smaller companies, but Google, Twitter and Facebook as well depending on your doctype.

I noticed the second affiliate uses an `iframe`. What doctype are you using for your HTML document? To make the validator "allow" frames, you need the frameset doctype!

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">`

Also, showing the actual validation errors would help a lot.

Comment: Actually, you do not need to use a frameset doctype, only a transitional doctype, for using `iframe`s.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is:

```
  <embed> cannot be a child tag of <object>
```

Same way

```
     <iframe> can't be a child tag of <a>
```

This is both logical and in the specifications. We do it that way sometimes though against the specifications, to support all browsers (Internet explorer 6 has problems with

```
<object>
```

tag for example)

In html5 there are almost no self-closing tags, you just leave them open.

[Read about specifications here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#html-elements)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to validate **always** your code is to write the offending code through javascript:

something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write( ...... your offending code .........);
</script>
```

Comment: That's a terrible way to avoid validation errors. If you have validation errors, that's usually an indication of something wrong. Simply ignoring it is foolish.